# Selenium Java Webdriver: Adding a string to an Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, cucumber

I have the folllowing piece of Java in which I want to add a String *inside* a statement:

```
     @and ("^I want to change fieldnumber \"([^\"]*)\" , remove whats inside and add the following text: \"([^\"]*)\"$")

    public void testscenario12345(String number,  String text) throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'template:view:<INSERT NUMBER STRING HERE>:item:view:1:item:')]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'template:view:<INSERT NUMBER STRING HERE>:item:view:1:item:')]")).sendKeys(text);
```

How can I add the number string in the above piece of code? To clarify, If I insert "4" in cucumber, I want the driver to find the element by Xpath, where the @name contains template:view:4:item:view:1:item:

Comment: Is it not simply something like `driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[contains(@name,'template:view:%s:item:view:1:item:')]", "1"))).clear();` ...as in your question actually has nothing to do with Selenium or XPath but merely "how do I format a string in Java so I can place a variable inside it?"

Comment: I didn't know that... I am just a functional tester who has been ordered to use selenium, so I figured that xpath and selenium were both bits of neccesary information in order to get everything working. But it works great now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,\"template:view:" + number+ ":item:view:1:item:\")]")).clear();
```

And you probably need the number to be const, that means:

```
public void testscenario12345(final String number,  String text) throws Throwable {
```

Comment: unfortunatly, doesn't work... "Illegal escape character in string literal", message under ":item:view:1:item:\"

Comment: did you try what @Arran suggested in his/her comment? The String.format solution, this should work. For your error, google for escape string

Comment: Yes, and now it works. Apparently, I misplaced a ". Thanks for the help!